# symfony Admin lte Bundle personalize datetype form

Tags: symfony, datepicker, format, symfony5, adminlte

I'm using the kevinPast adminLte bundle on symfony 5. Every datetype got their own format(dd-MM-YYYY) and you can't update it as a normal way by writing  'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd' inside the form for example. The problem occurs also for other datetype, like birthday.

I also try to use my own datepicker function to override the existing one, but it's a bundle, so it first not work, then it broke also the existing js.

You can see the different try i did:

```
            ->add('startTime', DateTimeType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            // @todo Can we make this format configurable?
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',  // must match data-date-format as defined in field.html.twig
            'minutes' => range(0, 55, 5)
        ])
```

it will show the data like that[image]

it use the block date_widget on twig, the single_text area

```
{% block date_widget %}
{% if widget == 'single_text' %}
    <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    </div>

    {% if type is not defined or type != 'date' %}
        {% if attr.class is defined %}
            {% set class = attr.class ~ ' timepicker' %}
        {% else %}
            {% set class = ' timepicker' %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class' : class, 'data-datepickerenable':'on'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% set date_pattern = '<div class="row">' ~ date_pattern ~ '</div>'|raw %}
    {{ date_pattern|replace({
    '{{ year }}' : '<div class="col-xs-4">{{ year }}</div>',
    '{{ month }}' : '<div class="col-xs-4">{{ month }}</div>',
    '{{ day }}' : '<div class="col-xs-4">{{ day }}</div>',
    })|raw|replace({
    '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
    '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month),
    '{{ day }}':   form_widget(form.day),
    })|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock %}

I also try to override it by using the following code:
Js part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: "DD/MM/YYYY h:mm"
});
```

});

form part

```
->add('startTime', DateTimeType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            //<input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="dd/mm/yyyy" data-mask="" im-insert="false">

            // @todo Can we make this format configurable?
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',  // must match data-date-format as defined in field.html.twig
            'minutes' => range(0, 55, 5),
            'attr' => ['class' => 'datepicker'],
        ])
```

This one overide the actual datepicker, but first doesn't fix the problem(you still have the standard format DD-MM-YYY) then it also broke the js used by the bundle(some navigation button doesn't work etc)

If I found a fix, i will also write the answer here.

Comment: Hi! I see this is your first post, welcome!
I removed some redundant lines to make it clearer. Please consider improving it by adding code examples and explaining better what's your final purpose, the tests you made and how the community can help you! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your advise, 
No problem, i'm actually working on it, i will edit my post with the actual update which don't work I done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after few work on it and if someone got the same problem, I found one solution, maybe not the best but it's work.
I checked the demo used with adminLte bundle on symfony (Kimai2)

So to be able to edit your calendar and format your date, you need to follow these step:
1 : create a dateTimePickerType and use it instead of default DatetimeType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DateTimePickerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['attr'] = array_merge($view->vars['attr'], [
            'data-datetimepicker' => 'on',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'placeholder' => strtoupper($options['format']),
            'data-format' => $options['format_picker'],
            'data-time-picker-increment' => $options['time_increment'],
        ]);
    }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'label' => '',
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'html5' => false,
        'format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'format_picker' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'with_seconds' => false,
        'time_increment' => 1,
    ]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return DateTimeType::class;
}


}
```

and on the formType

```
->add('startTime', DateTimePickerType::class, [
        'required' => true,
        'error_bubbling' => false,
        'label' => 'startTime',
        'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
        'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker-hours'],
    ])
```

Then the javascript part, you need to install daterangerpicker from [www.daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com)

and use these following function:

```
      const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

const Moment = require('moment');
global.moment = Moment;
require('moment/locale/en-gb');
require('daterangepicker');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-datepicker').daterangepicker({
        language: "en",
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        minYear: 1901,
        //maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
    });

$('.js-datepicker-hours').daterangepicker({
    language: "en",
    timePicker: true,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    locale: {
        format: 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }
    //maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
});
```